# Adding in a loop ARM assembly rpi

Tags: assembly, arm

I am very new to assembly, and am trying to add inside a loop while getting user input using scanf. This is my loop:

```
.data
.balign 4
format: .asciz "%d"
.balign 4
numCount: .word 0
.balign 4
counter: .word 0
.balign 4
prints: .asciz "%d\n"
.text

.global main
main:
ldr r5, =counter
mov r6, #0
bl loop
done:
ldr r0, =prints
//mov r1, r5
ldr r1, [r5]
bl printf

mov r7, $1
svc $0
loop:
    ldr r0, =format
    ldr r1, =numCount
    bl scanf
    ldr r1, =numCount


    add r6, r6, #1
    add r5, r5, r1


    cmp r6, #5
    beq done

    b loop
```

After exiting the loop, I try to printf the summed number (stored in r5?), with `ldr r1, [r5]` but that seg faults. If I do `mov r1, r5` it prints the address (i think?), something like 630150. I also tried putting `ldr r5, [r5]` and `ldr r1, [r1]` in the loop before add but that seg faulted as well. How come I segfault when I try to load a reference of a register into another one?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger? You might be surprised what you're adding in your loop.

Comment: `add r5,r5,r1` is incrementing the pointer `r5`.  You need to do something like `ldr rX,[r5]`, `add rX,rX,r1`, `str rX,[r5]` instead.  This will 'add' the scanf value to the 'counter' memory.  ARM does not have operations directly on memory.  Alternatively, you can clear `r5` like `r6` and then store the value at the end in main.